# Custom Connector for Power Bi giving error Details: "We cannot convert the value null to type Text."

Tags: powerbi

Thanks in advance!!

i created the custom connector for power bi using M language while testing the connector within the connector solution it is giving me the proper result.

but when i load the .mez file in power bi desktop and try to access the api Odata link it gives me following error.

is there any way to debug this and identify where is the actual error is?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by an empty cell in the query result that you're trying to translate into Text type.

You can edit the query in Power BI Desktop such that `null` and errors are treated as `BLANK` so that the type conversion goes through smoothly